# Android Material Toolbar surface color looks different on two different toolbars

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I'm trying to change the background color of the material toolbar to the surface color with:

```
android:background="?attr/colorSurface"
```

which works as expected (to simplify it I set the background color directly at the view and did not create a custom style for that). In order to define multiple colors for light and dark mode I created two colors.xml files. When in light mode the applied surface color looks as expected:

[image: light mode]

But when I'm changing to dark mode the two toolbars look like this (still both referencing the same color resource):

[image: dark mode]

The right toolbar has the correct background color, the left one not.

Then I checked if the same thing happens with every color I define in dark mode so I changed the surface color to my primary color. In dark mode it looks like this:

[image: dark mode with primary color]

So in this case the colors look the same, but when I'm using my surface color, it does not.

I also tried to change the Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface toolbar to Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar, but still the same result.

Comment: Check the [Elevation Overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) . You should use the `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface` style in your `MaterialToolbar`.

Comment: Setting `elevationOverlayEnabled` to false solved it, weird that this effect still gets applied when the elevation is set to 0. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So in this case the colors look the same, but when I'm using my surface color, it does not.

It happens because of [Elevation Overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays).
You can avoid the elevation overlays setting `elevationOverlayEnabled` to `false` in your app theme.

Just a final note. In your `MaterialToolbar` you should use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface"
        ..>
```

This style will automatically switch between the component's primary colored style in light theme and surface colored style in dark theme.

Comment: This answer is beyond useful. For literally YEARS now, I've been chasing material design styles around, wondering why material design is FORCIBLY altering the colors I have painfully selected, having no idea this 'feature' of dark mode was the culprit all along!

Comment: Oh my god, I just spent like 4 hours trying to figure out why my toolbar doesn't react to color changes in XML, only to find out that the style I was using and applying on the toolbar had `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar` as a parent instead of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.PrimarySurface`. Big difference! Tracing these errors is such a pain...